# What is the best method to use to delete/update an item from an array after a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I reached a dead end because I am not sure what to use to be able to access elements saved within the array and then remove them, what if the user decided to remove from the middle ? in this case pop wont work cus it removes from the end and it doesnt care if you give it index.

So I am looking for tips on how to implement the delete and update cases that I have within the following code:

```
const body = $("body");
const header = $("<header>Todo List</header>");
const unorderedList = $("<ul></ul>");
const testButton = $("<button>Add</button>");
const inputBox = $("<input></input>").text("Text.");
let toDos = ["wake up", "eat breakfast", "code"];



testButton.on("click", () => {          //Here we are adding input from user to the array and c

  toDos.push(inputBox.val())
  console.log(toDos)
  unorderedList.html("");        // either html or text to clear old data
   renderList();
});

const renderList = () => {

  toDos.forEach(function (element, index) {  //here we are adding whats inside todos into the unorderedlist
    const LI = $("<li></li>");
    unorderedList.append(LI);
    LI.text(element);

     const button_del = $("<button>Delete</button>");
      LI.append(button_del);
      button_del.on("click", () => {
        toDos.forEach(function (element, index) {
          const LI = $("<li></li>");
          LI.text(element);
          toDos.slice      // here I need a method to delete the value in the array 
            // since its unordered we can say
            /*array[index] = array[array.length-1];   it will replace example middle one with last one then we pop last one
              array.pop(); */
              //or use slice
      })
      });
     
    const button_Update = $("<button>Update</button>");
    LI.append(button_Update);
    button_Update.on("click", () => {   // here I need a method to update the value of the arrray and also replace it in the li
      console.log("update clicked") 
      x = prompt ("Update the value")
      // since its unordered we can say
            /*array[index] = array[array.length-1];   it will replace example middle one with last one then we pop last one
              array.pop(); */
              //or use slice            same as above   todo
    });
```

Note I tried using remove, to remove the li but if the user adds new items the old items just comes back, because we are not really removing them from the array and as soon as a new item is added to the array the old items will be re-created cus we only remove the html li if we use remove

Comment: You may want to look at the splice function, which allows you to remove an item (or items) from anywhere in an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete value and index with splice:

```
deleteAt = 1;
let toDos = ["wake up", "eat breakfast", "code"];
toDos.splice(i, 1);
console.log(toDos);
```

Delete only the value:

```
deleteAt = 1;
let toDos = ["wake up", "eat breakfast", "code"];
toDos[deleteAt] = "";
```

add then to Array with something like this:

```
function newValue(pNewValue) {
    stop = false;
    for (i=0; i<toDos.length; i++) {
        if(toDos[i]=="") {
            toDos[i] = pNewValue;
            stop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!stop) {
        toDos[toDos.length++] = pNewValue;
    }
}
```

DeleteAt could also be set with a value of the Array:

```
deleteAt = toDos.indexOf("eat breakfast");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I need to study splice a bit and will come back to this post to share what code I came up with